# Можно ли в тексте описывать мёртвого персонажа напрямую (без использования слов "тело" или "труп")?

Tags: синтаксис

Условия: все персонажи и читатель знают, что есть какой-то мёртвый человек (например, Андрей). Можно ли использовать второй вариант или это будет ошибкой?

1. Олег поднял тело Андрея и положил в гроб.
2. Олег поднял Андрея и положил в гроб.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ошибкой не будет точно.**
Е. Водолазкин, похороны Лавра из одноимённой книги:

> В полной тишине тело Лавра проносят сквозь толпу. На краю зеленого
> луга его кладут в траву. Трава мягко обтекает **Лавра**, выражая
> готовность принять его целиком, поскольку они друг другу не чужие. На
> этом лугу Христофор показывал усопшему схождение твердей, небесной и
> земной. Ноги Лавра связывают веревкой, от которой уходят два конца. В
> толпе слышны крики. Кто-то бросается разорвать веревку, но его тут же
> скручивают и оттаскивают в толпу. Если глядеть сверху, стоящие
> представляются невиданным скоплением точек, и лишь **Лавр** имеет
> протяженность (жирный шрифт мой — N.).